# Intermittent 'NOAUTH Authentication Required' error while using Jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I have setup a standalone Redis server (v 7.0.4). I have configured a password for it using `requirepass` config. I am using Jedis (v 4.2.0) as the client.

Following is the code for creating JedisPool to connect with Redis -

```
public JedisConnectionPool(final JedisPoolConfig poolConfig, final String host, int port, int timeout, final String password) {
    this.pool = new JedisPool(poolConfig, host, port, timeout, password);
}
```

I have a sequence of updates coming together, some updates are completed successfully, then I start getting following error -

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:96) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:137) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:316) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getOne(Connection.java:298) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.executeCommand(Connection.java:123) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.get(Jedis.java:4901) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
```

This error occurs multiple times, then following error comes -

```
2022-11-23 04:04:39.124 ERROR 62960 --- [ns-pool-evictor] redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory         : Error while validating pooled Jedis object.

redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: NOAUTH Authentication required.
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.processError(Protocol.java:96) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:137) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:316) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:243) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.ping(Jedis.java:356) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.validateObject(JedisFactory.java:211) ~[jedis-4.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.evict(GenericObjectPool.java:745) ~[commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.BaseGenericObjectPool$Evictor.run(BaseGenericObjectPool.java:160) ~[commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.EvictionTimer$WeakRunner.run(EvictionTimer.java:113) ~[commons-pool2-2.11.1.jar:2.11.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

After this the remaining updates are updates successfully to Redis.

As the same JedisPool is used to get Jedis Connection objects, I don't understand why there is NOAUTH error for some updates while others are completed successfully.

Can someone help resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possibilities is that the underlying socket of the `Jedis` object was actually closed and so its *AUTHed* state is cleared. This may happen if the `Jedis` object *borrowed* from `JedisPool` is *closed* twice (or multiple times). Because first `close()` would return the object to the pool but subsequent `close()` would cause the underlying socket object to be closed.

Check of the `Jedis` object borrowed from `JedisPool` is closed multiple times. If you use try-with-resources, one close operation could be hidden, e.g.

```
try (Jedis jedis = this.pool.getResource()) {
  // operations by jedis
  jedis.close(); // <-- first, visible close
} // <-- second, hidden close
```